# Get only count of objects in AWS s3 bucket using php sdk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to get count of total items in s3 bucket I am using AWS php sdk V3, is there any way to do this.

I am using iterator right now but it's working but taking so much time to get number of files, because bucket has more more than 20K files, here is my piece of code:

```
$iterator = $this->s3client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    'Bucket' => $this->bucket,
    'Delimiter' => '/',
    'Prefix'=>$path
));
$count = 0;
foreach ($iterator as $object) {
    $count++;
}
return $count;
```

Comment: Why don't you go through the [API's documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/)?

Comment: Looks like you didn't understood my question, though I edited my question to make it more clear, I hope you can understand now

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, help support the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96256/practical-cloud-computing).

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to write a program to call [ListObjects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_listObjects) and loop through the results (results might be paginated, requiring multiple calls).

Alternatively, Amazon CloudWatch maintains a [metric on the count of objects in each bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html).

Comment: Actually I am already listing files using `ListObjects` but I am using pagination with 200 items per page, but I need to show a total number of count as the top of page. and bucket has more than 20K file and it will keep increasing in future